# Is it possible to restore Windows 10 to an earlier restore point and back to current?

Tags: windows-10, restore, system-restore

I have some issues with an application which was running a few days/weeks (not more than 4 weeks) ago.
As I am not able to get it back to run, I would like to restore my system to a point where the software was running (as a test). Thus I maybe find the reason why the application won't run anymore.

My question is, if I do so, am I able to restore the system back (or "forward" in this context) to the current state after restoring to an earlier state? E.g. if I create a restore point right now.

<sub>Side note: I'm asking because, I never did restore Windows systems using restore points before.</sub>

Comment: Yes you can but be sure to make a manual restore point just before restoring to an earlier restore point. I would not try it myself with out making a full disk image before trying it, just in case something goes wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can restore your system to a specific point.

[image]

[image]

I have made several restores, when a machine goes wrong due to a sw malfunction an save me several times...

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the OP.... he'd like to be able to restore "forward" his machine... i.e. if I restore my computer back one week, can i then restore forward to a restore point I made today. If you can clarify your answer then it will be a good answer.

Comment: @Josem; Kinnectus is right. My question is, if I restore my system to the point of let's yesterday, can I afterwards restore to the state of today?

Comment: @Ramhound if you put it in a more elaborated answer, I would accept it... :)